# How to parse null from "null" string value

Tags: javascript

```
var hello = 'null';
```

How do I remove the quotes so var `hello` will truly equal `null` (and not a string)?  I'm curious on how to do this without using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: You don't. You test your value, and assign accordingly. A counter-question would be "what do you think you would concretely use this for?" because it's a good bet that what you're trying to do has a better way to do it.

Comment: Type in `var hello = null;`? Or do something like: `var hello = 'null'; var bar = hello === 'null' ? null : hello;`?

Comment: `'null'` is a string. It doesn't have any quotes, you can't remove them. How did you get this value? Further, what's wrong with `JSON.parse`?

Comment: The delete key?

Comment: I'm doing an assignment where I have to recreate JSON.parse - I'm going through each of the test cases one by one as I'm creating my function.  The test case I'm at now is reversing the stringified version of null and I can't think of anyway to strip null or undefined or false of it's quotes.  I know how to do it for strings and numbers, etc.  But null is a different beast and I've been trying everything!

Comment: Uh oh, 'recreate JSON.parse' - sounds like this is a *different* question/ask/task, and one that's much more complicated.. consider parsing this simple JSON text `{"null":null}`. Already well passed "how to compare string values and perform conditional actions".

Comment: There is something really wrong with your JSON. The stringify JSON should look something like this '{"someObj":null}' and not '{"someObj":"null"}'

Comment: it's pretty straight forward - if you want to assign `null` to a variable, assign `null`, don't assign `'null'` - just like if you want to assign `3` to a variable, you assign `3`, not `2`

Comment: Hi @AmanChhabra - I'm pretty sure you changed the title of my post.  In reality, my question has nothing to do with JSON other than I don't want to use JSON.parse...

Comment: Thanks everyone, it sounds like there is no simple way to achieve the desired results.  Therefore, I will rethink my approach on the whole assignment.  I may just see if the value deeply equals "null" - and then reassign it to null as somebody had suggested.

Comment: @dlearns I thought you are using for JSON. Anyways I have updated the title again

Comment: @AmanChhabra! Thanks - no worries

Answer (score 3):

Without JSON.parse, you cannot.

You can evaluate hello and alter its value later on in the code, which is much more real-world scenario.

```
hello = hello === 'null' ? null : hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `eval` or `parse` it from JSON (but `eval` is a terrible approach, I only mention it for the sake of this specific example). Like,

```js
var hello = JSON.parse('null');
console.log(hello === null);
```

Comment: `eval` for this is a sure-fire way to a disaster later on.  Your answer should list the caveats of such an approach, if you're suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `null`, I've just done this:

```
var a=1;
console.log(a);
a=null;
console.log(a);
console.log(a===null);
```

Results:

```
1
null
true
```

Though, null in JS is also a value.